# Can the return type be transformed for a GraphQL resolver

Tags: graphql, graphene-python, graphene-django

I have a `graphene-django` GraphQL API that I've added custom directives and middleware in that are very similar to what's offered by `graphene-django-extras`. There are several places where enum types are returned as a `graphene.Int()` field, I'd like to be able to use a directive to transform that a `graphene.String()` but it doesn't do that on its own. eg.

```
{
  foo {
    bar            # return Int
    # vs
    bar @readable  # return String
  }
}
```

Is that even possible? I'm looking through the `ResolvInfo` fields and there is something for the return type, but initial attempts don't work.

Edit: FWIW I don't think it matters that the API is currently developed using Python and Graphene. The question is more about whether or not GraphQL even supports this, I assume that if it does not then no language or library would make it possible.

Answer (score 1):

It's not really in the spirit of graphQL to have a variable output type.  So strictly speaking, you shouldn't try to do this.  That being said, instead you could easily add another field for the other type, i.e.

```
type Foo {
    barStr: String
    barInt: Int
}
```

and then just ask for the one that you want in your query.